# Can't access to Github's website on MacBook

Tags: flutter, macos, github, terminal

I can't open the GitHub website on any browser and it was running before
I'm not using any proxy server.
when I'm trying to open it in the browser or connect via terminal cloning or any communication with that website it gives me an error.
using MacBook(macOS Big Sur).
[image]

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that this problem is in any way related to Flutter or the terminal app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been Solved by changing my IP For Github

192.30.253.112 this was my Ip Adress For Githup befor I change it to

140.82.112.4

in /etc/hosts file by terminal

after the change I cleared the cache memory by command:

sudo dscacheutil -flushcache;
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder

Then It opens ^_^.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Somehow, this fixed it  If you can add the reasoning, it would be super!!

Comment: life saver, before that I cannot access github, stackoverflow ...

Answer (score 0):

1- From Mac's run this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

2- Then, enter the sudo password for your user to allow edit access to the file.

3- Use the arrow keys to move the cursor to the bottom of the file. On a new line, enter the testing server's IP address and the domain name you want to use for that IP address. In this example you can paste this:

```
140.82.112.4 github.com
```

4- Press `Control+O` to overwrite the existing file, then press Enter to confirm the overwriting. This saves the changes to the file.

5- Now, press `Control+X` to exit the nano editor.

6- Go to your browser and try to access github.

7- Cheers

You'll have a file similar to this one:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# Added by JK 
140.82.112.4 github.com
# End of section
```